# Polymer paper-card neon-animation focus

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am using paper-cards, that contains each element of a survey, which is wrapped by neon-animated-pages. When I have a long question or has multiple answers and have to scroll down on a phone, when I switch to the next question, which is shorter, is off the screen since you have to navigate down. How do I focus back on the top? Especially since the code I am on is currently running on the card that I am leaving, not the one I am navigating to.

```
<neon-animated-pages id="views" class="flex" selected="0" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
   <template is="dom-repeat" id="surveyquestions" items="{{survey.Questions}}" sort="_sort">
       <template is="dom-if" restamp if="{{isFormat(item.Type, 'Single-Select')}}" >
          <question-singleselect question="{{item}}" auth-Data="{{authData}}"></question-singleselect>
       </template>
        ....
    </template>
</neon-animated-pages>
```

Comment: Actually found it....after searching a long while. I tried to do this, but with the actual elements, but this works. document.getElementById("mainContainer").scrollTop = 0

Answer (score 0):

Actually found it....after searching a long while. I tried to do this, but with the actual elements, but this works. 
    document.getElementById("mainContainer").scrollTop = 0